# Problems with rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

First

```
ruby script/generate model Buyer id:integer name:string
```

after generating Buyer model, I did

```
rake db:migrate
```

it was working fine.

After 1 day I have executed below command

```
ruby script/generate model Seller id:integer seller_name:string
```

after generating Seller model, I did

```
rake db:migrate
```

I got an error, that Buyer table is already exists. why? we have different timestamp file.

```
class CreateBuyer < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :buyer do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :description
      t.decimal :price
      t.integer :seller_id
      t.string :email
      t.string :img_url

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :ads
  end
end
```

and another one is

```
class CreateSellers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :sellers do |t|
      t.integer :nos
      t.decimal :tsv
      t.decimal :avg_price

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :sellers
  end
end
```

I used Rails 2.3.11 and rake 0.8.7

Comment: Can you add your migration file so we can see the code?

Comment: You do not need to add the id fields in your migration, they are automatically added.

Comment: @Amit, Emily's answer below seems right to me. Also, if you're just starting with rails, you should consider using a more recent version of rails. Rails 3.1 just came out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure there were no errors generated when you ran the first migration? If an error is encountered while running a migration, the parts that were already run will still be in the database, but `schema_migrations` won't be updated with the migration timestamp. Therefore, the next time you try to run migrations, it'll try to re-run the first part of the failed migration, which will generate errors since it's already been run.

**Updated**: If you look in the error output you added (by the way, please add to the question rather than a comment, so it's formatted and the whole thing is included) you can see that the first `Execute db:migrate` is running the migration `CreateBuyer`. This confirms that your migration did not complete the first time you ran it or has since been unsuccessfully rolled back. To fix this, manually drop the `buyer` table, then rerun your migrations.

As a note, there's at least a couple issues in your `CreateBuyers` migration:

1. The table name should be `buyers` (plural) rather than `buyer` (singular)
2. The `down` part of the migration is dropping the table `ads` instead of `buyers`

The second problem there could explain why you're having trouble running migrations now, actually. If you rolled back the `CreateBuyers` migration, it would have dropped your `ads` table and left `buyers` in place.

Comment: I paste the code and here is my error trace
    rake db:migrate --trace
    ** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
    ** Invoke environment (first_time)
    ** Execute environment
   ** Execute db:migrate
   ==  CreateBuyer: migrating   ====================
  -- create_table(:buyer)
  rake aborted!
  An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

  SQLite3::SQLException: table "Buyer" already exists: CREATE TABLE "Buyer" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "name" varchar(255), "description" text, "price" decimal, "seller_id" integer, "email" varchar(255), "img_url"